# Running tests with flags from chrome cypress

Tags: testing, cypress, flags

I have some test cases that use webcam and our test enviroment needs for using webcam to have set flag in chrome --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure

How can I for some test sets have this set in chrome with cypress?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can pass flags to the chrome browser in Cypress by writing a Cypress plugin as seen in the official documentation here: https://docs.cypress.io/api/plugins/browser-launch-api.html#Usage.

Navigate to your `cypress/plugins` directory and add the following code

```
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('before:browser:launch', (browser = {}, launchOptions) => {
    // `args` is an array of all the arguments that will
    // be passed to browsers when it launches
  
    if (browser.name === 'chrome') {
      launchOptions.args.push('--unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure');
    }


    // whatever you return here becomes the launchOptions
    return launchOptions;
  });
};
```

Comment: This flag doesn't work anymore. Do you know for other workaround ?

Comment: NB: "The plugins file is no longer supported as of Cypress version 10.0.0."

See https://docs.cypress.io/api/plugins/browser-launch-api#Syntax